# Good CPU to replace my i5 CPU

Tags: motherboard

I already have a good video card of GTX 1060. So I do not need a CPU with GPU on it. See: [Skylake microarchitecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i7_microprocessors#Skylake_microarchitecture_.286th_generation.29). So skylake is not an option.

That being said, we do not have i9 right? i7 is like the best CPU there is.

ECS H61H2-M12 1.0
Enclosure Type: Desktop

The motherboard sucks I know. But well, what's the best CPU I can plug there. I can't easily upgrade my motherboard.

It's sucks because when I play overwatch I do not get 60 fps. Also the CPU is maxed out at 100%. I also do recording. This is my current CPU

3.00 gigahertz Intel Core i5-2320
32 kilobyte primary memory cache
256 kilobyte secondary memory cache
6144 kilobyte tertiary memory cache
64-bit ready
Multi-core (4 total)
Not hyper-threaded

Some CPU comes with GPU already on the same slot. I have no idea what it is for given that I already have a good GPU on my main board. So if that extra GPU on CPU cost more money I would rather a GPU less CPU.

This is my belarc advisor result

```
Operating System Windows 10 Professional (x64) Version 1511 (build 10586.545)
Install Language: English (United States)
System Locale: English (United States)
Installed: 8/7/2016 10:53:51 PM
Servicing Branch: Current Branch for Business (CBB)
Boot Mode: BIOS (Secure Boot not supported)
System Model ECS H61H2-M12 1.0
Enclosure Type: Desktop
Processor a 3.00 gigahertz Intel Core i5-2320
32 kilobyte primary memory cache
256 kilobyte secondary memory cache
6144 kilobyte tertiary memory cache
64-bit ready
Multi-core (4 total)
Not hyper-threaded
Main Circuit Board b Board: ECS H61H2-M12 1.0
Bus Clock: 400 megahertz
BIOS: American Megatrends Inc. 4.6.4 10/27/2011
Drives 1755.58 Gigabytes Usable Hard Drive Capacity
510.09 Gigabytes Hard Drive Free Space

Generic Flash Disk USB Device (8.05 GB) -- drive 3
ST1000DM003-9YN162 [Hard drive] (1000.20 GB) -- drive 0, s/n S1D0F680, rev CC4C, SMART Status: Healthy
ST3500312CS [Hard drive] (500.11 GB) -- drive 2, s/n 5VVAE8XQ, rev SC13, SMART Status: Healthy
TS256GSSD370 [Hard drive] (256.06 GB) -- drive 1, s/n B968689423, rev N1114B, SMART Status: Healthy
Memory Modules c,d 8170 Megabytes Usable Installed Memory

Slot 'A1_DIMM1' has 4096 MB
Slot 'A1_DIMM3' has 4096 MB
Local Drive Volumes

c: (NTFS on drive 1) *  255.27 GB   32.86 GB free       BitLocker†
d: (NTFS on drive 0)    105 MB  31 MB free      
e: (NTFS on drive 2)    500.11 GB   382.16 GB free      BitLocker†
f: (NTFS on drive 0)    209 MB  136 MB free         
g: (NTFS on drive 0)    265.19 GB   64.00 GB free       BitLocker†
h: (NTFS on drive 0)    734.70 GB   30.90 GB free       BitLocker†
* Operating System is installed on c:
† Encrypted volume.
Network Drives None detected
```

I also want high performance per price ratio.

Comment: Why do you want to switch your processor? Your integrated intel GPU won't cause any problems. Which processor are you using at the moment?

Comment: You're almost forcing yourself to move to AMD by rejecting a CPU with integrated graphics.  Its not just Skylake that has it, buddy.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths The choice of socket is the problem not favoring one manufacturer over the other, both have APU and non-APU platforms. This question is about an LGA1155 motherboard by the way and there have been processors for this socket without GPUs but there were also processors with higher marketing model numbers (see [performance rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_rating) for where this came from).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up buying Core i7 3770

I think people should see this

https://www.cpubenchmark.net/socketType.html

Basically I just check the benchmark number and see the price

```
Intel Xeon E3-1290 V2 @ 3.70GHz 9,925 $885.00*
Intel Xeon E3-1280 V2 @ 3.60GHz 9,757 $644.99*
Intel Core i7-3770K @ 3.50GHz 9,560 $560.50
Intel Xeon E3-1270 V2 @ 3.50GHz 9,462 $421.00
Intel Core i7-3770 @ 3.40GHz 9,328 $335.55
Intel Xeon E3-1275 V2 @ 3.50GHz 9,320 $434.00
```

Based on that I think Intel Core i7-3770 @ 3.40GHz is the best choice.

Basically the top 6 core have the same socket type and almost the same benchmark result. However, Intel Core i7 3770 is simply cheaper. It's only $335. I actually got a used one for $200 from tokopedia.com

Xeon 1290 is simply too expensive and not available on tokopedia.com

I didn't mention budget range and I actually do expect to spend $1k. However, because i7 seems to have far cheaper cost benefit ratio I simply pick i7-3770.

However, Adam told Intel Xeon E3-1290 V2 but the price is too expensive

Comment: The 1290 was available from $300 on ebay. It scores noticeably higher than the i7-3770 in both single and multicore benchmark scores: https://goo.gl/JzACBI

Comment: what? Oh no I already bought one.

Comment: 1290 is not available on tokopedia.com also the one in eBay may be used so not comparable. The difference of benchmark is not huge. 9300 vs 9900 and I am using your link.

Comment: 1) You did not specify in the question you were only willing to buy from tokopedia.com and so any answer which presumes this is a bad one. 2) CPUs which are not overclocked lose almost zero performance capability even after a decade of hard use. 3) 9900 vs 9300 is a significant deviation and would be noticed under certain circumstances, especially games, where the higher single-thread performance would lead to better overall smoothness in badly-threaded titles (which are still numerous).

Comment: I know. But not in tokopedia.com means it's not common. I should have mentioned that. I am not trying to get super duper high CPU. I am getting high end but common CPU.

Comment: I have no idea why commonality would be important to you, but whatever. You ought to reword your question, is what I've been trying to say, because as it stands my answer is the best answer, but it's obviously not what you really wanted...

Comment: low price per performance ratio is definitely a must but that's just common sense.

Comment: No, it's not. Why do you think high end parts exist? Reword your question. I'm done here.

Comment: xeon e5 2670 is pretty cheap too though probably for different socket. It seems that the price on passmark is a bit wrong. I got many at cheaper price than the price they list

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have a misconception regarding what is a "better" processor.

The i3/i5/i7 structuring is not such that all i7 chips will be better than any i5 or i3 chip, they are generalized and should only give you an idea of its general level of power and efficiency for average users. Most especially, it is not so easy to compare processors between generations (an i7 2700k and an i7 6770k are two horribly different beasts but they fill the same performance i7 shelf slot)

A third-generation i5 2500k will be much more powerful for computationally heavy tasks than the seventh-generation i7 6250, for example. This is because the 2500k is a four-core, overclockable chip designed for good single-threaded performance and was not designed with extremely low power consumption as the 6250 was. The 6250 is also a dual-core mobile optimized processor.

The fact that your CPU has an integrated GPU is irrelevant. You'd do yourself a disservice to specifically seek a CPU without an integrated GPU by drastically reducing the number of options that meet your criteria, let alone leaving you high and dry without video output should your GPU fail for any reason.

Long story short, if performance is what you are looking for you should just buy the i5 or i7 CPU that is at the top of your budget. If you have priorities other than maximum performance, you should seek advice from communities that seek the same goal (power efficiency, specific benchmarks, overclocking, etc). The CPU will have a GPU included. This is not a bad thing.

As a specific recommendation, the 1155 socket accepts Ivy Bridge CPUs (these start with a "3"). Assuming you seek performance, either the i7 3770k, or the lower budget i5 3570k are the options with the best price/performance. If your motherboard does not allow for overclocking you will not see a difference between these CPUs and the less expensive non-K variants (i5 3570, i7 3770).

Please keep in mind that upgrading your processor could very easily not change a single perceptible thing about your computer. You need to determine what your bottleneck actually is - for most people it is more often the amount of RAM installed.

Edit: From looking at your comments throughout this question, it is my personal opinion that you are not exactly sure where your priorities are. Specifically seeking a Xeon because it doesn't include a GPU without understanding what the Xeon was designed for doesn't make sense.

Being fair, you haven't explained **what** the machine is supposed to do. Are you doing heavy scientific computation on this machine? Are you running a server? We can only guess you're gaming on it because you have a GTX 1060 and that's a great budget gaming card. For gaming there is absolutely **zero** reason to purchase a Xeon over a similarly priced Core i-series processor and doing so may actually be detrimental to performance or your wallet.

Comment: What is ivy bridge? How do I know I have 1155 socket?

Comment: If I have no video card at all, will I be able to see something on screen? Usually something basic like low res windows?

Comment: So what should I buy?

Comment: Your motherboard specifies socket 1155 as can be found through a simple google search. To be clear, you very much can find a CPU without an embedded graphics processor. It's just completely silly to do so without good reason (note: you do not have a good reason)

Comment: The best suggestion I can give you is to not purchase anything right now and spend some time learning about building computers in general. All of the popular consumer processors from Intel include an integrated GPU not because they are trying to screw you out of money, but because it is a good value and nice to have in a pinch.

Comment: My good reason is I already have GTX 1060. Hence I no longer need GPU inside the CPU

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's just not a good reason this day and age.It may make sense "I have one gpu, I don't need another", but to go so far out of your way for something that gives you **less** for a **higher** price without understanding the nuanced difference in intended application for either chip is senseless.

Comment: I expect less price for CPU that doesn't have GPU embedded into it. I don't. Which is kind of confusing.

Comment: The logic you are using tells me one of two things: 1) You'd prefer an AMD CPU. AMD does not include an iGPU in their chips, however at any given consumer-grade price point Intel's chips absolutely smoke AMD. 2) I just don't understand **why** you are insistent on not having an iGPU when there is no better option for general application regardless of the iGPU.

Comment: The last line of your question states "I also want high performance per price ratio." You are not going to get a better price/performance ratio from any non-i series CPU. You also seem to believe that any i-series CPUs exist that do not have iGPUs, which is false.

Comment: so the i series (i5, i7) has the best price/performance ratio? Then why would anyone buy xeon? Obviously if having a GPU actually makes the processor cheaper I would buy that. I still have no idea how.

Comment: The Xeon is designed for tasks that efficiently utilize a higher number of cores. It is technically the "faster" processor but unless you are running specific programs that are designed with 8+ core utilization you won't feel any of that speed. So your choice is to spend more money for 4 more cores that you will practically never use, or spend a reasonable amount for just enough cores that come with useful extra features.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to make the assumption that you will be gaming, because you have a GTX 1060 and that is generally what people with that GPU want to do. If that is true, then it is probably the case that a new CPU would help you out. However, I am going to depart from the standard recommendation of "get another i5 that's faster" because your chipset can't overclock it (which is where much of the value of the i5 line lies for gamers), and in any case newer games are taking advantage of more than 4 cores now. For that reason, I recommend you get the **Intel Xeon E3-1290 v2** CPU. This CPU is [the most powerful CPU you can put on your socket](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/TYPE-Xeon%20E3-1200%20v2.html), with a stock speed of 3.7ghz and a turbo boost up to 4.1ghz.

Comment: Is xeon i7 or i5? What is the type of socket I have?

Comment: It is neither i5 or i7. You have the 1155 socket.

Comment: how much faster would intel xeon be compared to what I have now?

Comment: This may be controversial but this short answer is pretty too the point.

Comment: Because Intel Xeon CPUs lack an integrated GPU, they require graphics installed in an available PCI Express x16 slot. I like this aspect too.

Comment: About five bananas. Seriously though that question is unanswerable without context. I could say "a lot" but what would that really tell you? Its the same process as yours so take the core speed and the thread count increase and multiply those numbers, then do the same to your CPU and compare the results for a VERY rough estimate.

Comment: so xeon is the best for that slot. Let's see the price

Comment: Hmmm most recommend i7 http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Xeon-E3-1290-v2-vs-Intel-Core-i7-3770K

Comment: Also xeon e3 doesn't do much better than the current one.

Comment: @JimThio Never, under any circumstances, trust CPUBoss. For a more worthy comparison, I suggest checking out Passmark, UserBenchmark, and Cinebench. Those are real benchmarks, not site scrapers like CPUBoss is. Furthermore, when you say "Xeon e3 doesn't do much better than the current one" I have literally no idea what you are referring to, so I can't help you there. My Xeon is very much faster than your i5 now, both in terms of single core and multicore performance. I find it hard to believe any legitimate source would equate the two CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

> ECS H61H2-M12 1.0 Enclosure Type: Desktop
>
> The motherboard sucks I know. But well, what's the best CPU I can plug
>   there. I can't easily upgrade my motherboard.

No you got it all wrong, your attitude is… well…

Anyways, when I put *"ECS H61H2-M12 1.0"* into my favorite Internet search engine I get results like [this](http://www.ecsusa.com/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?CategoryID=1&DetailID=1289&DetailName=Feature&MenuID=24&LanID=11) stating that the motherboard has an LGA1155 socket and an H61 chipset¹, hence H61 in the name.

*"Skylake is not an option"* because of your limited knowledge about technology and interpretation (mis-)lead by made up and ever changing marketing terms, **but instead it's the complete wrong socket!** You are stuck with SandyBridge or IvyBridge.

- What's the actual name of your i5 CPU? Not all of them are quad cores on the desktop, I found the 3470T which is a dual core with 4 threads.
- Does it make sense to upgrade from one CPU with the same amount of cores within the same generation? Generally not if you're looking for 50 to 100% and beyond performance increases.
- You'd rather trade the GPU part on the CPU for more cores? That's unlikely on a board designed for *APUs* with a matching socket. There are enthusiast and server platforms with different sockets (required for more PCIe lanes, wiring to connect more RAM modules, etc.) though, that don't include GPUs on the CPU package.

The top processor you can get for the LGA1155 socket is the  2700K with 95W or 3770K with 77W TDP (more TDP doesn't have to imply it's better or vice versa). Why do I mention TDP? When you say you can't change the motherboard for some reasons I wonder if the enclosure was designed to accommodate beefier graphics cards and CPUs. You forgot other important things in your question so you may not have considered TDP limitations.

---

1. Launched with Sandy Bridge, your processor might be a Sandy Bridge CPU.

Comment: what is TDP? What does it stand for?

Comment: *"The thermal design power (TDP), is the maximum amount of heat generated by a computer chip or component that the cooling system in a computer is designed to dissipate in typical operation."* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_design_power

Comment: @LiveWireBT You should see Jim Thio 's latest question.......I cannot believe he has over 11k rep on Stack Overflow, yet has so little working knowledge of hardware.